# Outlook Redemption: How to add byte[] array as attachment

Tags: outlook-redemption

I'm receiving files as a byte array, and need to send these as attachments via Outlook/Redemption.

```
safeMail.Attachments.Add(data, OlAttachmentType.olByValue, DisplayName:attachment.FileName);
```

Results in the error:

```
{"Could not convert variant of type (OleStr) into type (Double)"}
```

I'm assuming because the Add() method is expecting a variant array? How can I convert the byte array into something that the Add() method will accept?

Comment: How do you declare and initialize the data variable?

Comment: Hi Dmitry - The data variable provided to me as a parameter, initialized in another system, where I believe they've just used System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path) method.

Comment: Can you show the declaration and the call to ReadAllBytes?

Comment: Also, is safeMail an instance of the SafeMailItem or RDOMail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `SafeMailItem` object probably wouldn't be the best choice as you'd still need to set the attachment file name. The RDO family of objects would be a much better choice.

Something along the lines :

```
  dim data(3)
  data(0) = "t"
  data(1) = "e"
  data(2) = "s"
  data(3) = "t"
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set Msg = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items.Add
  Msg.Subject = "attach as array"
  set attach = Msg.Attachments.Add(data)
  attach.FileName = "test.txt"
  attach.DisplayName = "test.txt"
  Msg.Save
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I've changed from SafeMail to RDOMail, and was also missing the attach.FileName.

'var att = mail.Attachments.Add(attachment.BinaryData, OlAttachmentType.olByValue, DisplayName:attachment.FileName);
        att.FileName = attachment.FileName;'